# New Facebook page not indexed, old one still is

Tags: google, facebook, search-engine-indexing

We migrated our client's old Facebook page to a new Facebook page several months ago. When I search for "(Client's Name) Facebook" in Google, the old Facebook page appears, but not the new one.

When I visit the old Facebook page indexed in Google I get redirected to the new page, with a message that says "duplicate page detected, "You were automatically redirected because (Client's Name) was merged to this page.".

The problem is that we would like the new Facebook page to appear in Google and not the old one. Why won't it index in Google? Is there something that we need to do in Facebook or is this Google's wrong doing?

Answer (score 1):

If the page redirects using a standard 301 then it would take sometime for Google to drop the page and amend the new one. New pages and changes to existing pages via redirects take time as said and this can take anywhere from 1 week to a couple of months if the page is regularly visited. You do not have control over the `facebook.com` domain so there is nothing you can do in web master tools to speed this process up as its out of your control.

Comment: Hi @bybe, I can't tell with what it redirects with (using Google Chrome and other online tools), but it's already been several months (6) and I think it should have updated itself by now. The Facebook page receives lots of likes and traffic daily.

Comment: Can you link us the page in question please.

Comment: Hi @bybe, sorry I cannot.

Comment: Then sadly I can't help further, You will need to check the redirect using firebug or something similar (Response Headers). Also within the iframe ensure there is noindex, or the robots is blocking... It shouldn't block it but it could in theory.